# ForEach - Index out of range?

Tags: swiftui

Why running this code shows "Fatal error: Index out of range"?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct MyData {
    var numbers = [Int](repeating: 0, count: 5)
}

@main
struct TrySwiftApp: App {
    @State var myData = MyData()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ChildView(myData: myData)
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .onAppear {
                    myData.numbers.removeFirst() // change myData
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    let myData: MyData // a constant

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(myData.numbers.indices) {
            Text("\(myData.numbers[$0])") // Thread 1: Fatal error: Index out of range
        }
    }
}
```

After checking other questions,
I know I can fix it by following ways

```swift
// fix 1: add id
ForEach(myData.numbers.indices, id: \.self) {
  //...
}
```

or

```swift
// Edited:
//
// This is not a fix, see George's reply
//
// fix 2: make ChildView conforms to Equatable
struct ChildView: View, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ChildView, rhs: ChildView) -> Bool {
        rhs.myData.numbers == rhs.myData.numbers
    }
    
    ...
```

My Questions:

How a **constant value** (defined by let) got out of sync?

What ForEach really did?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let me give you a simple example to show you what happened:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var lowerBound: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(lowerBound..<11) { index in
            Text(String(describing: index))
        }
        
        Button("update") { lowerBound = 5 }.padding()
 
    }
    
}
```

if you look at the upper code you would see that I am initializing a ForEach JUST with a Range like this: `lowerBound..<11` which it means this `0..<11`, when you do this you are telling SwiftUI, hey this is my range and it will not change! It is a constant Range! and SwiftUI says ok! if you are not going update upper or lower bound you can use ForEach without showing or given `id`! But if you see my code again! I am updating lowerBound of ForEach and with this action I am breaking my agreement about constant Range! So SwiftUI comes and tell us if you are going update my ForEach range in count or any thing then you have to use an `id` then you can update the given range! And the reason is because if we have 2 same item with same value, SwiftUI would have issue to know which one you say! with using an `id` we are solving the identification issue for SwiftUI! About id you can use it like this: `id:\.self` or like this `id:\.customID` if your struct conform to Hash-able protocol, or in last case you can stop using id if you confrom your struct to identifiable protocol! then ForEach would magically sink itself with that.

Now see the edited code, it will build and run because we solved the issue of identification:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var lowerBound: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(lowerBound..<11, id:\.self) { index in
            Text(String(describing: index))
        }
        
        Button("update") { lowerBound = 5 }.padding()
 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your explanation is really easy to understand.

Comment: @joshmori: Do not forget that you confused the SwiftUI Error message system. The true message is this: `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

Answer (score 4):

Things go wrong when you do `myData.numbers.removeFirst()`, because now `myData.numbers.indices` has changed and so the range in the `ForEach` showing `Text` causes problems.

You should see the following warning (at least I do in Xcode 13b5) hinting this could cause issues:

> Non-constant range: not an integer range

The reason it is not constant is because `MyData`'s `numbers` property is a `var`, not `let`, meaning it can change / not constant - and you do change this. However the warning only shows because you aren't directly using a range literal in the `ForEach` initializer, so it assumes it's not constant because it doesn't know.

As you say, you have some fixes. Solution 1 where you provide `id: \.self` works because now it uses a different initializer. Definition for the initializer you are using:

> ```
> @available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
> extension ForEach where Data == Range<Int>, ID == Int, Content : View {
>
>     /// Creates an instance that computes views on demand over a given constant
>     /// range.
>     ///
>     /// The instance only reads the initial value of the provided `data` and
>     /// doesn't need to identify views across updates. To compute views on
>     /// demand over a dynamic range, use ``ForEach/init(_:id:content:)``.
>     ///
>     /// - Parameters:
>     ///   - data: A constant range.
>     ///   - content: The view builder that creates views dynamically.
>     public init(_ data: Range<Int>, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Int) -> Content)
> }
> ```

Stating:

> The instance only reads the initial value of the provided `data` and doesn't need to identify views across updates. To compute views on demand over a dynamic range, use `ForEach/init(_:id:content:)`.

So that's why your solution 1 worked. You switched to the initializer which *didn't* assume the data was constant and would never change.

Your solution 2 isn't really a "solution". It just doesn't update the view at all, because `myData.numbers` changes so early that it is always equal, so the view never updates. You can see the view still has 5 lines of `Text`, rather than 4.

---

If you still have issues with accessing the elements in this `ForEach` and get out-of-bounds errors, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68974606/how-can-i-get-my-button-to-reflect-the-bool-of-my-environmentobject/68975334#68975334) may help.

Comment: This line "The instance only reads the initial value of the provided `data`" is really helpful, thanks. But I think myData in ChildView remains constant. What really happened is a new ChildView Struct created, but ForEach only reference the original ChildView.

Comment: @joshmori: You confused SwiftUI error message function, it should show you this message: `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!

Comment: @joshmori It _does_ remain constant, but only until `ChildView`'s init is called again. Then, `myData` is whatever is passed in. When you remove the first element of `number` in `onAppear(perform:)`, this recomputes the body because it is a state change (`@State`). We then have a different value for `myData`, the second time it is initialized, but `ChildView`'s `body` now has a different range for `myData.numbers.indices`.

Comment: @George `myData` in two struct instance is different. But it remains the same within each instance. The `UI instance` of ChildView reference different struct instance after change, but ForEach `function instance` only reference the first struct. This is my current understanding.

Comment: @joshmori When you ran `myData.numbers.removeFirst()`, `myData` in `TrySwiftApp` has now changed. That instance is copied when it is passed into `ChildView`, so they both have an identical copy - but different memory addresses because `MyData` is a value type. In the `ForEach`, the range you provided in the init stays for as long as that `body` is active - basically until `ChildView` disappears for whatever reason, which in this case only happens if the app is restarted. However, the data you pass into `Text` now has less elements, so it fails to get the last index.

Comment: @joshmori The reason that the range in the `ForEach` doesn't change is because of the `ForEach` initializer you chose - the one without the `id` parameter. And as quoted in the question, the initializer you used should **only** be for a constant range.