# How to redraw a child view in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I have a ContentView that has a state variable "count". When its value is changed, the number of stars in the child view should be updated.

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var count: Int = 5
   
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Stepper("Count", value: $count, in: 0...10)
      StarView(count: $count)
    }
    .padding()
  }
}

struct StarView: View {
  @Binding var count: Int
   
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      ForEach(0..<count) { i in
        Image(systemName: "star")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know why the number of stars are not changed in the child view, but I don't know how to fix it because the child view is in a package that I cannot modify. How can I achieve my goal only by changing the ContentView?

Comment: If you can't change `StarView`, that is a faulty package because the view code is incorrect. Can't you just recreate the view, like you have here?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the incorrect `ForEach` initializer, because you aren't explicitly specifying an `id`. This initializer is **only** for constant data, AKA a constant range - which this data isn't since `count` changes.

The documentation for the initializer you are currently using:

> It's important that the `id` of a data element doesn't change unless you
> replace the data element with a new data element that has a new
> identity. If the `id` of a data element changes, the content view
> generated from that data element loses any current state and animations.

Explicitly set the `id` like so, by adding `id: \.self`:

```
struct StarView: View {
    @Binding var count: Int

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(0 ..< count, id: \.self) { _ in
                Image(systemName: "star")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

<sup>Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69080578/9607863).</sup>

Comment: @BigComRen Glad it helped! To help others easier discover this answer in the future, you can mark it as accepted (tick), much appreciated!